# Unable to resolve infinite redirect loop?

Tags: php, facebook, heroku, facebook-fql

I have hosted my facebook app on heroku just now, I followed the tutorial commit my work push it to remote. I refreshed the hosted page url It showed the first page as it was showing earlier when I used the top left facebook login button it asked the permission of public information and then nothing happen after an interval it throws "This webpage has a redirect loop"

This is the url:
https://glacial-dusk-9875.herokuapp.com/

i have added following lines in index.php

```
  // Here is an example of a FQL call that fetches all of your friends that are
  // using this app
  $app_using_friends = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1'
  ));
  // my code/changes start here
  $app_liked = $facebook->api(array(
      'method'      =>  'fql.query',
      'query'       =>  'SELECT uid,page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=' . $pageId
  ));
var_dump($app_liked);
```

Appreciate @phwd help I was able to see myself successfully accessing the page, but now again the same problem after just single refresh:

```
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

Comment: Seems to work for me, try clearing your cookies.

Comment: oh thanks, working good now.

Comment: Still have the same problem: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: Whatever the problem it's most likely not the code posted, consider looking in your error_log while locally testing.

Comment: I am trying local while stuck at this error: Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed thrown in C:\Users\najm\glacial-dusk-9875\sdk\src\base_facebook.php on line 886

Comment: I have figured out this: ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 601: Parser error: unexpected end of query. thrown in C:\Users\najm\glacial-dusk-9875\sdk\src\base_facebook.php on line 1271

Answer (score 2):

Check your PHP SDK SHA or version. I have a guess that you are couple revisions behind

The heroku template references the PHP SDK @ 98f2be163c96a51166354e467b95dd38aa4b0a19 which doesn't cater for having the newest CA cert.

https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-php

May want to update that git submodule

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

```
16d696c138b82003177d0b4841a3e4652442e5b1 Merge pull request #69 from anankan/master
0b0d711498fb4a283ce84802c34e49a491134a1f Added the extra param: appsecret_proof to the oauth api calls
bf99924386be074da30a8e9d6bbcb49d3333da12 Merge pull request #57 from kilotaras/vulnerability_bug
7324e40d74599a747e81af358c6ef5405539a5dd Fixed a vulnerability with signed requests
aecd4bfba0b5bd8e237269732cea7da2f8f1a34c Merge pull request #50 from evanadelman/master
1899bf9f0a88aa885db03febb6980ec7bc0ad1e7 Merge pull request #45 from favrik/master
2041c94716e6186b6f9dd3ce2314977899f9ea02 clarified apache specific lookup for ssl & added ability to loo
ca9472b3312dab3fdcfbffb4e45eb091f582dcb7 Avoid trying to reuse spent authorization codes
1a84329fcc8b0fa0afaf3617cd9fb15a25eff95e Use `empty()` for signed request value check
c81dfdea4f6ae9c902cf367dc52dc205f4d7c4f5 bump version to 3.2.1
bac1e25e420770867efb3286d9ee2cfd7addaea5 fix broken tests and remove some broken ones
42961c500761dd62099bf633a5db7182c00c1678 updated cert bundle to use the current curl bundle
98f2be163c96a51166354e467b95dd38aa4b0a19 Merge pull request #35 from bfanger/master
339f504a24520c2f53ac08ad03efaf9f26ae4420 Updated version number
```

Comment: Thanks alot it fixed the issue. hug to stackoverflow members

Comment: I am using localhost for development of heroku app but I still am still having loop issue:

I have figured out this: ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 601: Parser error: unexpected end of query. thrown in C:\Users\najm\glacial-dusk-9875\sdk\src\base_facebook.php on line 1271

I have also come to know that this happens when you are having lot of facebook app on a single domain within sub directories.

Comment: @justnajm the code for `page_id` isn't above though my guess is that there is an issue with your FQL queries